# PHP: how can i avoid warnings when using strpos() with null or empty strings?

Tags: php, compiler-warnings

i'm pulling data from a db and sometimes the value returned is an empty string or null.  when i try to evaluate in general for the presence of a set of chars in the returned value, it generates a warning.  i'd like to know how to evaluate without generating a warning and thus slowing down PHP.  here's what i'm doing:

```php
if(strpos($db_result, $valueToCheckFor) !== false) // do stuff
```

the value of $db_result is often empty or null because there's nothing there, which is fine because i want to write data to it.  occasionally, data will exist and i'll want to `CONCAT` to the data, but only if the `valueToCheckFor` isn't there.  for example:

```php
valueToCheckFor = 'AP'
db_result = ''          <--- yep.  want to write to this (very common - generates Warning)
db_result = 'fnork'     <--- yep.  want to write to this (less common)
db_result = 'fnorkAP'   <--- nope.  do NOT want to write to this (rare)
```

so i'm not concerned about the check *working*, because it works fine. i **AM** concerned that everytime i get an empty string (or null) it cranks out a warning, like this:

```php
Deprecated: strpos(): Non-string needles will be interpreted as strings in the future.
Use an explicit chr() call to preserve the current behavior
```

i looked into `chr()` but cannot fathom how it applies to this.

how do i modify my `if` statment to avoid getting these warnings?

Comment: Don't run the `strpos()` check if the string is empty? Surround it with an `if()` to eliminate the possibility. I'm never sure whether you can add in a check for `empty()` like this: `if (!empty($db_result) && strpos($db_result, $value) !== false) { ` or whether it'll evaluate the right-hand one even if the left is not true.

Comment: It's not the value of `$db_result` which is producing this warning, it's the value of `$valueToCheckFor`. If that is an integer, you will get the warning you are seeing. `$db_result` being `''` or even `null` will not generate it.

Comment: ah! ok! yes, the value of `valueToCheck` is sometimes just a number. so i guess i should just cast it to a string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

by casting the `$valueToCheckFor` to a string, this solved the problem:

```php
if(strpos($db_result, (string) $valueToCheckFor) !== false) // do stuff
```